# Expression Engine Conditional Based on status of a page

Tags: expressionengine

I am trying to turn on and off a section of navigation based on if a published entry has a status of open or closed.

So my intent is something like:

```
{if particluarpage == "closed"}

content

{if:elseif}

content

{/if}
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI... There is an EE StackExchange site now for EE questions if you want to use it: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/221/week/expressionengine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of achieving this. The simplest option would probably be to issue a query via the [query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/index.html).

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT status FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_id = '4'"}
{if status == 'open'}
    Show Block A
{if:else}
    Show Block B
{/if}
{/exp:query}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't that be something like this?

```
{if "{exp:channel:entries channel="yourchannel" entry_id="X"}{status}{/exp:channel:entries}" == "closed"}
    content
 {if:else}
    content
 {/if}
```

Maybe you'll need the dynamic="no" parameter too.